# Even after logging in , every url is redirecting to login page (spring security)

Tags: spring, security

I am using spring security for my crud application. After logging in employee list has to be displayed. if i need to perform any operation in that page, it is redirecting to login page even after logged in.

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String log(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,Model model){

        try{
        userService.login(user);
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "redirect:/employees";
        }catch(Exception e){
            return "redirect:/accessDenied";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployee(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        model.addAttribute("listEmployee", employeeService.listEmployee());
        return "employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp,Model model){

        this.employeeService.addEditEmployee(emp);
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String removeEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id,Model model){

        this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "redirect:/employees";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.getEmployeeById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listEmployees",employeeService.listEmployee());
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "employee";
    }
```

this is my spring security config file

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
         <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/> 
        <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/employees" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/> -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login"
                             default-target-url="/employees" 
                             authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager >
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service authorities-by-username-query="" 
                                        users-by-username-query="select userName,password from user where userName=? AND password=?"
                                        data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Here what i need is, once if i login i should perform all the operations . i need session to remember that i was logged in.

Comment: You are working around Spring Security instead of using Spring Security. Let Spring Security handle the login process instead of writing your own.

Comment: what does your `userService.login(user) do?

Comment: public User login(User user) {
  user = (User) session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("userName", user.getUserName()))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("password", user.getPassword()))
    .uniqueResult();
  return user;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please to try  this : `<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>`

why you are handling the login post on your controller?! why you don't use spring security for login?